# Can I use separate accounts for Windows Phone & Xbox Live?

Tags: 8.0, xbox-live

I prefer to keep my online gaming accounts associated with an e-mail account which is separate from my normal e-mail. So, the Xbox Live account connected to my Xbox 360 is not registered to the same e-mail address I used for registering my Windows Phone.

When I went to download games for my phone, it seems that the system created a new Xbox Live account which is associated to my Windows Phone account. I expected to have an opportunity to use my existing Xbox Live ID, but did not see that option.

Is there a way I can configure my phone to use an Xbox Live ID which is not the same as the Microsoft account I used for registering my phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the answer is NO.

The Microsoft Account you inform will be used in Games Hub for Live ID, Picture Hub for SkyDrive integration, for Me tile updates, Messages app with Messenger and Facebook and so on.

You can change the Microsoft Account your phone uses but it will change everything I mention.

Comment: This *really* grinds my gears. I wonder if I can get MS to change/merge my Xbox Live profile to my phone's Microsoft account? If not, I may just forego using my phone for anything actually attached to my Xbox.

Comment: You can get in touch with Microsoft to migrate your gamertag to another Microsoft Account/E-mail.

Comment: I'm finding out now that it's a *lot* more painful than it should be - particularly because I inadvertently allowed my phone to create a new gamertag already. To do the transfer, I first have to take my Phone account's gamertag and move it to a *third* account that doesn't already have a gamertag. Then I need to *wait 30 days* before I can repeat the transfer process to get my preferred gamertag moved to my Phone account.

Comment: Correction: 30 day timer is *before* I can start the whole process - new gamertags can't be transferred for 30 days.